# Союз "как" с запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, все ли в порядке с пунктуацией?

1. Ему нравилось, что о нем говорят как об очень образованном человеке.
2. Его слова она растолковала как признание в любви.
3. Свой восьмидесятый день рождения он отметил, как и все прочие за последние пять лет.

Answer (score 1):

В третьем предложении может быть **разный смысл**:

(1) Свой восьмидесятый день рождения он **тоже** отметил, как и все прочие за последние пять лет.

(2) Свой восьмидесятый день рождения он тоже отметил **так же**, как и все прочие за последние пять лет.

Поэтому **для определенности его надо редактировать**.